# Kubernetes Network Policy for Internet Egress

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I'm trying to create a Kubernetes network policy that allows pods to egress out to the internet to connect to external resources (like Azure SQL) but not allow them to connect to other pods inside the cluster. I've succesfully blocked all egress, but when I add the policy below to allow internet access, it instead allows access to everything, internal and external.

Can anyone confirm whether this should work, or if I'm missing something?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-internet-egress
  namespace: client-namespace
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels: {}
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
        except:
          - 10.0.0.0/8
          - 192.168.0.0/16
          - 172.16.0.0/20
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

This is running on an Azure AKS cluster, with the Azure Network Policy addon running.

Comment: It seems this is an issue with the Azure network policy implementation. I span up a new AKS cluster using Calico for network policy and it worked as expected.

Comment: Maybe you can add an answer to show the solution and a short description.

Comment: I have a rule that looks the same as your, but somehow it doesn't work for me. I am working with Google Kubernetes Engine (Calico).